# Uncaught DOMException on route change hls.js React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http-live-streaming, hls.js, plyr.js

I use [plyr.js](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr) to create a video player.
Caught an error with `hls.js`:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'buffered' property from 'SourceBuffer': 
This SourceBuffer has been removed from the parent media source.
```

It happens when I change video `src` on route change.

**My player:**

```
import React from 'react'
import HLS from 'hls.js'
import Plyr from 'plyr'

const Player = ({src}) => {

  const [player, setPlayer] = useState(null);
  const video = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {

    const node = video.current;

    // Thought it would help, but no
    const destroy = () => {
      if (window.hls) {
        window.hls.stopLoad();
        window.hls.detachMedia();
        window.hls.destroy();
      }
    };

    if (node) {
      if(!player) setPlayer(new Plyr(node, {captions: {active: true, update: true}}))
      if (HLS.isSupported()) {
        destroy();
        window.hls = new HLS();
        window.hls.loadSource(src);
        window.hls.attachMedia(node);
      } else node.src = src;
    }

    }, [src, player]);

  return (
    <div>
      <video ref={video} src={src} controls/>
    </div>
  )
};
```

Comment: What is the video type? Did you try another video src?

Comment: @AhedKabalan, mp4

Comment: Did you try another video source? I think that the issue with the video format.

Comment: @AhedKabalan, hm, lemme check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed an `useEffect` so it works now:

```
import React , { useEffect, useRef, useState,context }  from 'react'
import HLS from 'hls.js'
import Plyr from 'plyr'

const destroyHLS = () => {
  window.hls.stopLoad();
  window.hls.detachMedia();
  window.hls.destroy();
};


const Player = ({src}) => {

  const [player, setPlayer] = useState(null);
  const video = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => setPlayer(new Plyr(video.current, context)), [src]);

  useEffect(() => {

    let ignore = false;

    if (HLS.isSupported()) {
      if (window.hls) destroyHLS();
      window.hls = new HLS();
      window.hls.loadSource(src);
      window.hls.attachMedia(video.current);
    } else video.current.src = src;

    if (ignore) player.destroy();

    return () => {
      ignore = true;
    };
  }, [player, src]);

  return (
    <div>
      <video ref={video} src={src} controls/>
    </div>
  )
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a `key` prop to your `<video />`.

```
<video ref={video} src={src} key={src} controls />
```

I also see many others use a `<source />` tag.

```
<video ref={video} key={src}>
  <source src={src} />
</video>
```

Comment: Hi, it works well but also removes plyr styles once `src` changed :/

Comment: :( oh no. Hmmm. It might be worth mentioning that `useEffect` is only called when the component first mounts, not when the state changes. Maybe you can put some of that logic outside of it? Don't know much about plyr

Comment: Thanks for your help, Brandon, I found a solution, it doesn't work because of my `useEffect`, I will give you an reward in 20 hours :)